# When and how should I write two answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, formatting

For certain questions, there may be multiple ways of doing something. This is the question that persuaded me to write this:

- [Fastest way to get a photo from iPhone to Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127716/fastest-way-to-get-a-photo-from-iphone-to-mac)

My existing answer is a way to get the photo to the Mac over Photo Stream using a folder. However, I also have a second way, completely unrelated to Photo Stream yet still a very quick way to transfer photos.

How should I include this second answer? Should I edit my existing answer to include a second answer, in this way:

> #### Photo Stream method
>
> [content]
>
> #### App method
>
> [content]

Alternatively, should I write a second answer?

> [content mentioning Photo Stream method]

> [content mentioning app method]

…and if so, should I introduce the answers with a title?

> #### Photo Stream method
>
> [content]

> #### App method
>
> [content]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, don't sweat it.  I have used both methods.  Sometimes I choose which is most appropriate based on the particular wording of the question, so in this instance is says "What's the fastest way", well if I have two ways, only one can be fastest *to me*, but someone else may find the other one faster.  In this case I might present multiple answers.  If it was worded *is there a fast way to..* then I might include them both in one.

There's no hard and fast rule, it's just what you feel is appropriate.  If, for example I have an answer that has votes, and maybe even an accept, and I come up with an alternate way some time down the line, it's a little disingenuous to edit it in to the existing answer, so I would normally add another, for example.